# TabLayout using fragment dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I just tried to use TabLayout, and I have some issues to understand how it works. Fragments is new for me too.
So this is the point, My first activity when the user launch the app is a tutorial. I use one fragment for each part of the tutorial. What's more, I know that only the view pager is enough for the user I just want to try it with the tab layout too.
So, in the first fragment I have a TextView and a Button. And when the user click on the button, I want to switch to the second tab for the second part of the tutorial etc.

Now the first fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_tuto_first_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:id="@+id/valider_tuto_first_fragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The java file :

```
public class TutoFirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public TutoFirstFragment()
    {

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tuto_first_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

The onCreate() method on the Activity named Tutoriel :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    replaceContentLayout(R.layout.tutorial_activity, super.CONTENT_LAYOUT_ID);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tutorial_toolbar);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tuto_tab_layout);
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tuto_first_fragment_tabhost);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tuto_view_pager);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,  R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));

    toSecondFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valider_tuto_first_fragment);
    toSecondFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() + 1);
        }
    });
}
```

To the issue is that I can't make the onClickListener in the activity and I don't understand how to do it in fragments.

Thank you for your help by sharing me your knowledge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your fragment implement `OnClickListener`:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
```

Then implement the `onClick` method  in your fragment

```
@Override // LISTENER
public void onClick(View v) { do your stuff there }
```

Now to assign his listener to an object, use the following:

```
yourWhateverObject.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now you can switch your tab position in this if you have access to the pager as an example:

```
pager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't get it. In the `onClickListener` of the first fragment I want to set the current tab to another position. But I have access to the tabLayout only in the activity and not in the fragment.

Comment: Then you have to give a reference to the TabLayout to your fragment. You can consider using an instance in your activty, with your activity as a singleton accessible in your fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially wondering how your fragment can communicate with it'a parent activity.

The cleanest way to do this, is to define an *interface* in your fragment, have your activity implement it, and then override `onAttach(..)` to setup a callback.

There is an example for this here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface